# Divert calls during a time interval

Tags: calls

How to set-up a phone so that the calls are diverted during a time interval (e.g. from 8:30 to 17:00)?

If it matters, I have a Huawei Ascend P2 running on Android 4.1.2 Jelly Bean and on the UK's "3" mobile network.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about your device but on my HTC One I have a "Do Not Disturb" function which I can schedule for a particular time. However I think this will block everything; text messages, emails etc. If thats not what you want then I suggest you try [Tasker](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=net.dinglisch.android.taskerm&hl=en). There is a call divert option in there.

Comment: *Tasker* was my first thought as well – almost nothing it cannot do. Apart from that, you might check into [call blockers](http://android.izzysoft.de/applists.php?topic=cat;id=23#group_97). I've never used any of those, but rawly remember some had kinds of "timers" integrated.